# Correct way of returning snapshot length of Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Future method which return type is

> Future < List< Map< dynamic, dynamic>>>

In my WidgetBuilder, I would like to know the length of the snapshot but I don't know how to get the length:

```
   : FutureBuilder(
                    future: getCollection(), // Return Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>>
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                         return Center(
                            //replace this with a loading icon
                            child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
                       } else {
                           return ListView.builder(
                                 itemExtent: 90,
                                 itemCount: snapshot. ? , <==  How do I excess the length?
```

Assuming it's a list of Maps. I tried the following:

`snapshot.data.data["someAttributeName"]` 
but it gave me a null exception. Any ideas how to get the length

Comment: If you set the type of data in your snapshot, you'll have access to its properties through autocompletion. `builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> snapshot)`

Comment: @JordanDavies, works. I can mark it as an accepted answer if you could please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the type of your `AsyncSnapshot`, you can access its properties through autocompletion:

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> snapshot)
```